# What is wrong js and php objects

Tags: php, ajax

In test.php i have this code

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['user'])) {  
echo "hi";
  }
exit; ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
var user = {
    'name': 'Wayne',
    'country': 'Ireland',
    'selected': new Array(1, 5, 9)
};
var userStr = JSON.stringify(user);
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {user: userStr},
    success: function(response){
        //do whatever.
    }
});
</script>   
</head>
</html>
```

I changed it, but isset($_POST['user']) = false because my page is empty so why?
All this code is in test.php

Comment: Why are you loading two versions of jQuery from different hosts?

Comment: The first time you visit the page, `$_POST['user']` won't be defined (since you haven't posted the form yet). You need to check if it exists before trying to use it: `if (isset($_POST['user'])) {  ...your code  }`

Comment: I tried only with onw or two it didn't help

Comment: If you want to send a response from PHP to your Ajax request, you should either put the PHP code on top of the page (before any other output) and have an `exit;` when it's done, or the request will just return the complete page (including your HTML/JS).

Comment: You seem to be doing your ajax call at the top of the same page as you do your dump on - therefore if you are expecting to browse to test.php and see the dump, then that won't work - you'll only ever see anything inside the ajax result or if you post directly to test.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not printing / visualizing the actual response of the ajax.

```php
<?php
if (isset($_POST['user'])) {
    $user_string = $_POST['user'];
    var_dump($user_string);

    $user_asarr = json_decode($user_string, true); // associative array
    var_dump($user_asarr);

    exit();
}
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var user = {
    'name': 'Wayne',
    'country': 'Ireland',
    'selected': new Array(1, 5, 9)
};
var userStr = JSON.stringify(user);
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {user: userStr},
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response); // check out your console!
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
NULL

Comment: in console i had this after changing my code like this

Comment: Sorry in the first part I was wrong, jQuery does that for you. I fix this

Comment: oh thank u. in console it was printed. Can I use that like php object?

Comment: No, look at your console, there is written something like `string(...) ...`. You need to `json_decode` it before use it like php object/array